# extracting an array from a database in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

im currently trying to extract a table from my database (articles) and the table article and put it in an array but im not sure weather or not it wokred because i dont know how to print an array. i was following this link.

http://phpscriptarray.com/php-arrays-tutorials-tour/how-to-extract-mysql-database-data-into-php-array-variable.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// connect to DB
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db('article', $conn);
if (!$db_selected){
    die("can't use article : " .mysqli_error());
} 
// extract databases table to PHP array
$query = "SELECT * FROM `articles`";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$number = mysql_numrows($result);
$article_array = array();
$x = 0
while($x < $number)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $artic = $row['name'];
    $amount = $row['quantity'];
    $article_array[$artic] = $amount;
    $x++;
}
echo count($article_array);
//echo "hello";

<?
```

even the echo hello wont work and im not sure if i was supposed to put a name and quantity in:

```
$artic = $row['name'];
$amount = $row['quantity'];
```

Comment: you said that `echo "hello";` is not working? did you have php server at your end or not? what server you are working? xampp,wamp or lamp?

Comment: There's no `mysql_numrows` function. mysqli_ and mysql_ functions are **different** APIs. What for is the ending `<?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing object oriented with procedural style. Your query and loop should look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `articles`";    
$result = $conn->query($query);
$article_array = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $artic = $row['name'];
    $amount = $row['quantity'];
    $article_array[$artic] = $amount;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Also your PHP closing tag is faulty - should be `?>` or omitted.